# pymysql query formatting, TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str

Tags: python, pymysql

So I was writing a sql query to get data from the database using python pymysql library. The user will enter a year as a text field in HTML form and display the data associated with this year. I'm using this code and I'm keep getting error for it.

```
sql = "SELECT 'Name' From 'winners' WHERE 'Year'=%d"
c.execute(sql, (textfield,))
```

Can someone show me how to fix this please ? Thank you

Comment: use %s instead of %d

Comment: I tried that but it gave me this error
args = (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the ...se near ''winners' WHERE 'Year'='2000'' at line 1")

Comment: So what is not clear about the error message? `textfield` is a string, not a number. `%d` means you expect there to be a number instead. You could convert the textfield to a number with `int()` perhaps?

Comment: @jondoyle: you are using the wrong quotes, see [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11321491)

Comment: what part is wrong ? Cause I learned it from a tutorial 
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyMySQL

Comment: @jondoyle: the tutorial uses backticks, not quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues:

- You are using incorrect syntax. `'` single quotes are used to define string values, not to quote table and column names. You probably meant to use backticks, `` ` ``. See [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491)
- You are passing in a string where your query parameter states you wanted to receive an integer. SQL parameters only support `%s` format placeholders, however.

Corrected code would look like this:

```
sql = "SELECT `Name` From `winners` WHERE `Year`=%s"
c.execute(sql, (int(textfield),))
```

Note the `int()` call; you want to select on integers, not strings, if your column type is NUMBER or similar.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, changed the quotes and I converted to int but still giving me this error:
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str 
      args = ('%d format: a number is required, not str',) 
      with_traceback = <built-in method with_traceback of TypeError object>
for this Line
c.execute(sql, (int(textfield),))

Comment: @jondoyle: ah, sorry. I see how pymysql is handling this now; it is a normal SQL parameter and that's always a `%s` in this case.